# Should I tell a training center about my company's name?

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

I am going to a join a training institute to get expertise on some skill.

A weird quirk about this is that the trainer might be interested in knowing in which company I work.

I am not interested in telling him that. Or should I?

If not , would that still be professionalism?

Comment: Don't they already know that if your company pays for it?

Comment: Why don't you want them to know?

Answer (score 3):

The company one works for is typically not considered confidential - many people share this information publicly on social networks.

If asked, especially in a professional setting, you can't really avoid sharing this information without appearing rude or at least evasive.

If you don't mind appearing rude or evasive, you can say it's confidential.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce yourself as "I am working for a company in the ... sector" or "a company that produces ..." or similar.
This doesn't reveal the name and there is a chance for the trainer to see you don't like to tell more details so they don't even ask for it.

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted. I have seen many people do that successfully.

Comment: Some ... don't know better but still think they have to contribute to the world. If not meaningful than at least by clicking down :-)